# Loopcut into many objects at once

Tags: modeling, scripting, loop

Hey guys i am building a city and i want to make a loopcut into every single building from the bottom in the exact same point! Lets say i want every building to have a loopcut at 3 m from ground ...do ihave to do it in every building manually or there is a quicker way?

Comment: maybe use the knife? K to activate, Z to cut through, C to cut horizontally...

Comment: the only problem with that is that the city is not on a flat surface!  so everything is in different heights! i  was looking something less tedious than having to go building by building separately!

Comment: my bad I thought that it was possible to cut several objects at once with th knife

Comment: its ok mate  thanks anyway!

Comment: It may still be possible with the knife. If no building's bottom is above another buildings top. - Then: Do what moonboots suggested in the first comment and cut all buildings, but at an arbitrary height. Then press g twice and slide all loops to the bottom. (Make sure auto merge is turned off) And finally press g, z, 3 to move all loops up by 3m.

Comment: i will try that one thanks

Comment: Try to add a plane crossing all objects at the desired height for the loopcut, then pick that plane as a cutter in boolean modifiers properties (booleans should be added to all objects, there're ways to spread modifiers). This is hacky way (since cutting with non-manifold geometry and stuff boolean doesn't like) but it should work

Comment: @michaelh  Thanks man it  worked great!

Comment: Good to hear! Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

**Bmesh script.**

[image]

Script to bisect each selected mesh globally 3  units above its bounding box lower corner.

Edit `height = 3` to adjust.

Test script, select any or all of the objects to bisect, in OBJECT mode and press run script.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh

# global coordinates
height = 3 
plane_no = (0, 0, 1)

meshes = set()
bm = bmesh.new()
for ob in context.selected_objects:
    if ob.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    me = ob.data
    if me in meshes:
        continue
    meshes.add(me)
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    bbox = [mw @ Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box]
    h = (bbox[1] - bbox[0])
    if h.length > height:
        print(f"Cutting {ob.name}")
        print(h, h.normalized(), bbox[0])
        mwi = mw.inverted()
        bbox[0].z += height
        bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(
                bm,
                geom=sum((bm.faces[:], bm.edges[:]), []),
                plane_no=plane_no,
                plane_co=mwi @ bbox[0],
                )
        bm.to_mesh(me)
        me.update()
        bm.clear()
bm.free()
```

Comment: bF to the rescue :D

Comment: Def not the master of the quick illustration. Find peek can be slippery took 3 goes to get that bad one, wanted to switch into edit mode .. must have swiped a lamp..

Comment: my problem is 
A)Many buildings are combined as one object
B)i have a terrain that has different heights! so i want each edge in the z axis to be subdivided so that te distance from the ground will be x

Comment: Please edit any extra detail (like this) into question. Maybe a pic or two too.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a good place for the *Bisect* tool, here, from the <kbd>T</kbd> toolbar, all objects selected, and all faces selected in Edit mode:

[image]

Settings adjusted in its  <kbd>F9</kbd> panel. (I'm cutting at 1m)

EDIT: To achieve this via the UI, if all the buildings start at different heights:

1. Open a Timeline, and stash all the objects' locations as a keyframe. (With all selected, <kbd>I</kbd>, key Locations)
2. On another frame,  *Header menu > Object > Align Objects > Negative Sides,* in Z. Other alignments, too, if that makes the tool easier to use. (Key again, if you like.)
3. Proceed to *Bisect*, as above,  in Edit mode.
4. Delete the 'aligned' key, if you've made one. The buildings will jump back to their original positions.

Comment: i dont have a plane as a terrain! my terrain is uniformed with hills so i cant bisect from a plane! (if i try to bisect i get wired angle results)

Comment: In that case, you should probably consider finalizing your modeling process on the buildings before scattering them on your terrain.

Comment: if i add a loop cut i each building can i somehow manage each selected point  afterwards to be a specific distance from the bottom?

Comment: @alexkar See edit, if all your buildings start at different heights.

Comment: Issue looks like multiple buildings at diff levels in one object  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215610/loopcut-into-many-objects-at-once#comment364104_215619  could be for the THB (too hard basket)

Comment: @batFINGER Separate by loose parts. But if they aren't loose parts.. it could be.. the 'That'll Learn Ya', basket, as they say, over the river, in Cornwall.

Comment: _"Whale oil beef hooked"_

Comment: "Toyed moy 'orse to a gaap in the 'edge, aan, when oi kem baak, there it was, gone!". etc. :D